# HttpException in Handler.php line 133: This action is unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have created an application using laravel 5.3 and it is working fine on localhost but after I uploded all my code on a server I have this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException in /home/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php line 133: This action is unauthorized.
```

This is happening when I try to call functions whithin my controllers using post.

This is one example:

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
         Route::post('admin/store/', 'Admin\AnnouncementController@store');
    });
});
```

Controller

```
protected function store(AnnouncementRequest $request) {
    return Auth::user()->id;
}
```

How can I fix this? Why is this not happening on my localhost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not certain why your controller's function has `protected` access modifier. Try changing that to public and see what happens. Also the reason why something is working locally but not working on remote host 9/10 for me was cache ( try php artisan cache:clear locally and see if it still works ).

Comment: Hi peaceman, thanks for your reply but none of the above worked for me.

Comment: From my research `This action is unauthorized. ` appears when you are trying to access a resource you don't have sufficient privileges to access. What is happening in your custom Request  ( AnnouncementRequest) are you returning false from authorize method.

Comment: I believe the same thing you are.  As you see I do have my post action inside a middleware identified as admin. Thing is, I tried to move that to public but still get the same error.

Answer (score 56):

Check that your `AnnouncementRequest` file is set to return true from authorize function. The default is to return false.

Comment: Please, put this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> If you can use CustomRequest method for validation then make sure to
>   your authorize() return true. If you can set false then its never call
>   your function as well throw the error 
>   **This action is unauthorized**
>
> Solution

```
class CopyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
         return true;   //Default false .Now set return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Default function return false so change it as shown below

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

or also can use Auth in the Request

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for what I saw, there can be a lot of situations for this scenario. In my case, I was using a custom FormRequest named **AnnouncementRequest**. Inside that class I was checking for a role property on the auth user.

```
// before
public function authorize() {
    if(Auth::user()->role_id === 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My mistake was to use === instead == for validation. So after fixing that everything is working just fine.

```
// after
public function authorize() {
    if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Anyway why did it worked on localhost but did not on the server remains a mystery for me...

Comment: For your kind information, You should have told @peaceman to post his comment as an answer rather then your own..!

Comment: You are absolutely right, @BasheerAhmedKharoti. The same error in my code got corrected with the Peaceman suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The authorize() function by default it returns false,
return true, your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

In your Request file default not enable authorisation

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

if you enable your request file here showing that code.

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```