# Class App\Http|Controllers\ValidateRegistraion does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form request using `php artisan make:request ValidateRegistration`. It created a `ValidateRegistration.php` file under `App\Http\Requests\` directory. After this I have made changes in the `store()` function of my registration controller ie `UserController.php`, means I have changed it

**FROM**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    // Save the data
    User::create(request(['fname','lname','phone','email','password']));

    // redirect to home page
    return redirect('/registration-success');
}
```

**TO**

```
public function store(ValidateRagistration $request)
{   
    // Save the data
    User::create(request(['fname','lname','phone','email','password']));

    // redirect to home page
    return redirect('/registration-success');
}
```

And added `use App\Http\Requests\ValidateRagistration;` at the top of the `UserController.php` file. But when I submit the form without filling anything it shows me an error which is `Class App\Http\Controllers\ValidateRegistraion does not exist`

**EDIT**

Added `UserController.php` and `ValidateRegistration.php` files.

> UserController.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Requests\ValidateRegistration;

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $title = "Registration";
        return view('/registration', compact('title'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ValidateRegistration $request)
    {
        //// validate requested data
        //$this->validate(request(), [
        //    'fname'     => 'required',
        //    'lname'     => 'required',
        //    'phone'     => 'required|size:10',
        //    'email'     => 'required',
        //    'password'  => 'required'
        //]);

        // Save the data
        User::create(request(['fname','lname','phone','email','password']));

        // redirect to home page
        return redirect('/registration-success');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

> ValidateRegistration.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ValidateRegistration extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'fname'     => 'required',
            'lname'     => 'required',
            'phone'     => 'required|size:10',
            'email'     => 'required',
            'password'  => 'required'
        ];
    }

    /**
    * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'fname.required' => 'Firstname is mandatoy',
            'lname.required'  => 'Lastname is mandatory',
            'phone.required'  => 'Phone is mandatory',
            'phone.size'  => 'Phone must be 10 digit',
            'email.required'  => 'Email is mandatory',
            'password.required'  => 'Password is mandatory',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the use statement - you have 2 completely different spellings in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ValidateRegistration.php I modified the authorize() function. It was returning `false`. Changed it to `true`. It is working now.

> From

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

> To

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

spot the difference in your class names:

ValidateRagistration
ValidateRegistraion

and I'm guessing it should read *ValidateRegistration*, clear up typos, they will only confuse things later

Comment: I have corrected the spellings but still same issue. I have edited my question to add two files. Please check

Comment: @ShaunBiswas would you like to post the error you are getting now? where are the functions `request()` and `redirect()` defined?

Comment: I am getting the same error which is `Class App\Http\Controllers\ValidateRegistration does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

at the top of UserController.php swap the positions of the `namespace` and `use` lines, `namespace` should always be first

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ValidateRegistration;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
```

and `ValidateRegistration.php` is in your App\Http\Requests directory

Comment: I did exactly like you suggested. And `ValidateRegistration.php` is in my `App\Http\Requests` directory. Now I got a new error that is `(1/1) HttpException. This action is unauthorized in Handler.php (line 133)`

Comment: did you check out this post? [HttpException in Handler.php line 133: This action is unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215055/httpexception-in-handler-php-line-133-this-action-is-unauthorized)

Comment: Yes I checked.

My controller looks like ->

`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
`